# PHP select box on select echo details

Tags: php, json, api, crm

**UPDATE**
I have edited code below to reflect @Andy_D suggestion.
However now I am displaying initial choosen option but the onchange I can't seem to get to work. Any help? Thanks

---

I want to echo out values based on select option from the select box which has been populated with organisation name values per the below `foreach`loop

I am using this library for API calls to Insightly CRM https://github.com/Insightly/insightly-php

```
<?php
    include 'authentication.php';
    $orgs = $i->getOrganizations();
    global $organID;
    global $organName;
?>
<select id="target" >
        <?php foreach ($orgs as $org) { ?>
            <?php
                $organID = $org->ORGANISATION_ID;
                $organName = $org->ORGANISATION_NAME;                   
                $street = $org->ADDRESSES[0]->STREET;
                $city = $org->ADDRESSES[0]->CITY;
                $state = $org->ADDRESSES[0]->STATE;
                $postcode = $org->ADDRESSES[0]->POSTCODE;
                $country = $org->ADDRESSES[0]->COUNTRY;
            ?>                      
            <option value="<?php echo $organName ?>"><?php echo $organName ?></option>
        <?php }?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#target").on("change", function() {
                var orgName = "<?php echo $organName ?>";   
                var orgID ="<?php echo $organID ?>";
                var orgName = "<?php echo $organName ?>";
                var street = "<?php echo $street ?>";
                var city = "<?php echo $city ?>";       
                var state = "<?php echo $state ?>";   
                var postcode = "<?php echo $postcode ?>"; 
                var country = "<?php echo $country ?>";

                $(".organisation").html(orgID + "<br>" + orgName + "<br>" + street + "<br>" + city + "<br>" + state + "<br>" + postcode + "<br>" + country);
                });
        </script>
        </select>

        <div class="organisation"></div>
```

Thanks appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in PHP only, you'll need to reload the page. You can submit your select element and get the ORGANISATION_ID from the params, then use that id to print out the info.

Another way to do this would be using Javascript. First, pass the organization info to JS. Something like:

```
var orgs = <?php echo json_encode($orgs) ?>;
```

Then listen for the 'change' event on your select element, grab the chosen id, and populate the info using values from your orgs JSON.

You have PHP embedded in your JavaScript for your on change callback. That code won't run as it is being called in the browser, not your server. For your current approach to work, you need to store all your data in a JavaScript variable (what I suggest above), and use that in your callback. You can set a unique HTML id for each field that needs to change, and use that id to change the content ie

```
document.getElementById('orgName').innerHTML = orgs.orgThatWasSelected.name
```

Comment: Hi Andy thanks for your suggestion I have used javascript print out result however I am only able to print out initial option select..seems the stored values are not updating on change, if you can help that would be great!